# Receiving incorrect test error for javascript code

Tags: javascript

It tests the number of elements in listNodes. The answer is 10 but my ListNode has 0 elements.
[Code is given in the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOooR.png)

Comment: Shouldn't you test the .length somewhere?

Comment: Hi, Kweave26. Please edit your question to include the code, the desired results, the results your getting, and a question.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing what you want, what the context actually looks like and what the solution could be. As Jonathan M already commented, for giving proper help we need a proper question, proper description of the problem and context/code. Please give this in the future.

Luckily for you, the solution seems pretty obvious: The task is to assign a NodeList of all nodes with the class name "top-language". But you are searching for nodes with the class name "top-**ten**-language". Although I am guessing, I am sure this is the solution. Cheers